# Rails - display category name on views via relationship tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables that I put relationship with blog and post_categories. Below is the schema:

```
  create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.integer "status", default: 0
    t.bigint "post_category_id"
    t.index ["post_category_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_post_category_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_blogs_on_slug", unique: true
  end

  create_table "post_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Now what I am trying to do is to display the category name instead of category id on my blog index.html.erb file. I did the following but did not work:

```
<tbody>
    <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= blog.title %></td>
        <td><%= blog.body %></td>
        <% PostCategory.all.each do |c| %>
          <% if c.id == blog.post_category %>
          <td><%= c.name %>
          <% end %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', blog %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(blog) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', blog, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Note: I also tried accessing it directly via  `<td><%= blog.post_category.name %></td>`but did not work still.

Any idea how can I display the category name instead of category id associated?

Comment: If I used this  `<td><%= blog.post_category %></td>` it gives me something like this: `#<PostCategory:0x007fafd058f070>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you schema provided, it is noted that PostCategory object has many Blog objects

model changes,

```
class PostCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs
end

class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post_category
end
```

view changes,

```
<tbody>
  <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= blog.title %></td>
      <td><%= blog.body %></td>
      <td><%= blog.post_category.name rescue 'No post category present for this blog' %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', blog %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(blog) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', blog, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: RAY Tried this already but got undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: updated answer, it is your data problem as association and schema is proper but you do not have data as per association. use of `try` method can handle issue

Comment: @MarcSolva for `blog.post_category_id`, there must be id present in table `post_categories`

Comment: It works but is it safe to just let "try" method handle the work? is this a good practice? Also can explain the association issue more?

Comment: RAY - do i need to add a migration id for the post_categories table to solve this issue?

Comment: @MarcSolva I am not getting why answer got downvoted! First if your blog is having post_category_id but surprise is you do not have post_category object for that present. So basically you can use try to avoid problem or change as per my update

Comment: @MarcSolva i can see upvoted wrong answer provided by cryptex, it will go under moderator inspection, they will take proper action

Comment: Not sure about that. I did not upvoted anything yet. Anyway back to the issue.

Comment: @MarcSolva Can you tell me you have numbers of blogs for one post category? right ?

Comment: Use safe navigation and `||` rather than rescue (`blog.post_category&.name || "string"`)

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej What is `blog.post_category&.name` ? I did not get role of  `&` in your comment

Answer (score 0):

model changes,

```
class PostCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs
end

class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post_category
end
```

view changes,

```
<tbody>
  <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= blog.title %></td>
      <td><%= blog.body %></td>
      <td><%= blog.post_category.try(:name) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', blog %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(blog) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', blog, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column post_categories.blog_id does not exist
LINE 1: ... "post_categories".* FROM "post_categories" WHERE "post_cate...

Comment: First reset your database and start creating

Comment: Why you are calling post_categories.blog_id

Comment: Downvoted! `blog belongs_to :post_category` as `blogs` table have foregin key  `post_category_id`

Comment: `belongs_to :post_category as blogs` place this on my blog model but I got this: compile error

  `# GET /blogs.json
  def index
    @blogs = Blog.all
  end

  def post_category_0`

Comment: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  tap it says

Comment: If I used this <td><%= blog.post_category %></td> it gives me something like this: #<PostCategory:0x007fafd058f070>

Comment: hence there is post_category present

Comment: SO just add the condition <%  if blog.post_category.present?  %><td><%= blog.post_category.map(&:name).join(", ") %></td> <% end %>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186026/discussion-between-marc-solva-and-cryptex-technologies).